# Why don't my elements inside the div become horizontally scrollable?

Tags: css, sass

Inside my HTML:

```
<div class="certificates-container">
        <button class="certificates-exit-btn">&#8656;</button>
        <div class="carousel">
            <ul class="carousel-list">
                <li class="slide" data-active>
                    <img src="images/img1.png" alt="Certificate Image #1">
                    <p>lorem10</p>
                    <p>2022</p>
                </li>
                <li class="slide">
                    <img src="images/img2.png" alt="Certificate Image #2">
                    <p>Lorem10</p>
                    <p>2022</p>
                </li>
                <li class="slide">
                    <img src="images/img3.png" alt="Certificate Image #3">
                    <p>lorem10</p>
                    <p>2022</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Inside my scss;

```
.certificates-container{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 99999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    .certificates-exit-btn{
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        font-size: 1em;
        padding: 0.5em 1em;
    }

    .carousel{
        display: block;
        .carousel-list{
            border: 1px solid blue;
            padding: 2em;
            display: flex;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            .slide{
                border: 1px solid green;
                width: 400px;
                img{
                    display: block;
                    width: 100%;
                }
                p{
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want `.carousel-list` to be horizontally scrollable. But green bordered `.slide` elements overflows the container and become invisible and looks like this;
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKSae.png) It does not become horizontally scrollable they just overflows the container and i can't put certain pixel width to them. How should I do that?

Comment: I stripped some stuff to make it easier to look at, but do you essentially mean this behaviour [in this example here?](https://codepen.io/misterManSam/pen/ExErrqp). If so, the secret source is to not allow the flex child to shrink and also set the `flex-basis` as `400px` instead of the width. Shorthand `flex: 0 0 400px` = don't grow, don't shrink and set the initial size as 400px.

Comment: Yes I was looking for something like in the example. Thanks @misterManSam

Answer (score 0):

overflow-y property specifies whether to clip the content, add a scroll bar, or display overflow content of a block-level element when it overflows at the **top and bottom edges**. You need to use overflow-x for this.

Comment: That still doesn't fix it as `position: fixed;` has to be removed too

Comment: yeah it still doesn't fix problem is with the fixed position :/

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
.carousel-list {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```